# Fragment is acting weird in my recyclerview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments, android-recyclerview

Somehow I can't seem to find a reason my fragments are acting alot different than I expect them to act.

What I want to accomplish:

[image: what I want to accomplish]

What I get atm:

[image: what I get atm]

My question - how can I reach the goal here - in my situation, getting few blue squares next to each other with text from my DB examples.

XML:

**activity_main**

**rec_item**

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:layout_margin="4dp">

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/category_image"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true"
    android:contentDescription="@null"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    android:background="#b7b7ff"/>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:minHeight="48dp"
    android:paddingBottom="16dp"
    android:paddingLeft="16dp"
    android:paddingRight="16dp"
    android:paddingTop="16dp"
    android:background="#E237474F"
    style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Subhead.Inverse"
    tools:text="TEST"/>

</FrameLayout>
```

**rec_list**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@+id/recycler_view"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `cursor.getString(0)` to `cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex("name"));`

You are assuming the `name` is the zero'th column in the cursor, and it's probably not--`_id` appears to be the zero'th column. Above is the proper way to get the value for a certain column. (Alternatively, if you you only `select name` from the table, or if you explicitly order the columns as in `select name, _id, ...`, then your existing code would also work.)

With this change you should see category names, although you will have many duplicates because every time your `MainActivity` is created, it inserts four more rows into the table. Since you do not have any [uniqueness constraint](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html#constraints) on the `name` column, SQLite is happy to insert these names again in new rows.

Finally, your `ImageView` has no source image yet, and you haven't given it explicit dimensions, so I suspect its width and height are both zero. Given that you want to make a grid, `match_parent` seems like the wrong thing to use for the item layout's root element anyway (at least for the height). You might consider using a [`PercentFrameLayout`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/percent/PercentFrameLayout.html) as the root of the item layout so that you can specify an aspect ratio.

Comment: 1. How can I skip duplicates? I tried to use "name TEXT unique", but I still see them.
2. Didn't know that adding ''src'' would give such a difference on interface. Now I got - https://img.exs.lv/e/z/ezeliitis/Screenshot_2016-11-20-23-06-14.png, but I still have to get a padding around each picture? I tried to play with PercentFrameLayout, but It didn't gave me any success.

Comment: @ThingsILove1996 If you changed the `create table` sql statement, you need to either delete the existing database (so that a new one gets created) or perform a version upgrade of the database. Changing the `create table` sql in java code will not affect any data already stored.

Comment: Karakuri - thanks. What about 2. To get some padding around each fragment? How should I approach it?

Comment: @ThingsILove1996 Put padding in your item layout, or use an ItemDecoration that doesn't draw anything.